# integration of product of a gaussian pdf and a student-t pdf

Tags: normal-distribution, linear-model, random-variable, t-distribution, integral

I want to perform the following integration wrt $x$:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt(2\pi\sigma^2)}e^(\frac{-(y-hx)^2}{2\sigma^2})[(1+\frac{x^2}{b})^{-(\frac{b+1}{2})}]dx$$

Here first part is a gaussian random variable (treating $y,h,\sigma$ as constants and the second part is student-t distribution with parameter $b$.
Does this have any closed form or represents any other kind of distribution. I am unable to figure out.

Comment: This is a convolution and thus represents the distribution of the sum of two independetn random variables. This problem is studied in this article: https://doi.org/10.2991/978-94-6239-061-4_6. I could not check the text because it is behind a paywall, but you can try to contact the authors for a copy.

Comment: It is not a member of any well-known family of distributions and likely has no nice analytical formula.  What statistical problem is this integral intended to solve?  Often, information about that context helps point the way towards appropriate analyses.  For instance, maybe you only need to know a particular moment of this distribution, or maybe you only need to know its tail behavior.  Those problems are both readily solvable.  Help us out by providing that additional information.

Comment: @cdalitz Thank you. This is of great help. The book talks about product of student's t with normal distribution of zero mean, however I have non zero mean. So I feel I am still stuck.

Comment: @whuber Thank you giving it attention. The problem involves computation of messages for sum-product algorithm over factor graph based on linear model $y=Hx+n$.

Comment: Now If I open $(y-hx)^2$ I will get below three terms:-
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\int e^{\frac{-(y-hx)^2}{2\sigma^2}} (1+\frac{x^2}{v})^{\frac{-(v+1)}{2}}dx =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}[ e^{\frac{-y^2}{2\sigma^2}}\int(1+\frac{x^2}{v})^{\frac{-(v+1)}{2}}dx + \int e^{\frac{-h^2x^2}{2\sigma^2}}  (1+\frac{x^2}{v})^{\frac{-(v+1)}{2}}dx + \int e^{\frac{hyx}{\sigma^2}}(1+\frac{x^2}{v})^{\frac{-(v+1)}{2}}dx]$$

The first two integrals can be calculated. Any idea about the third integral??

Comment: @Aashna you cannot decompose the intergral this way, because the third integral diverges either for $x\to\infty$ or for $x\to -\infty$, depending on the sign of $y$.

Comment: @cdalitz yaa got you. Thanks.